# nginx do not execute php files

Tags: php, nginx

I install nginx with help of this [site](http://www.bogotobogo.com/php/nginx_install_configure_run.php) 
and when l go to `http://localhost/index.php` it gives me empty screen. This my default:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/html;

index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name localhost;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

    location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            deny all;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
#   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#
#   # With php5-cgi alone:
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php5-fpm:
#   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: did you create in your root(/var/www/html) an index.php file?

Comment: However I strongly recommend this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Yes, index.php is there

Comment: try this for php location: `location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    } `then reload nginx and php-fpm

Comment: Now its "502 Bad Gateway"

Comment: Find out whats wrong) It was listen = 127.0.0.1:9000 in www.conf. Now all working, thanks a lot)

Comment: Ill answer so you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for php location:

```
location ~ \.php$ { try_files $uri =404; fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$; fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; fastcgi_index index.php; fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; include fastcgi_params; }
```

then reload nginx and php-fpm(if you get a bad-gateway is a php-fpm error(reload it))